# Compiler does not give error when using list initialization which will cause information loss

Tags: c++, c++11

In c++ primer(5th), it mentioned:

> When used with variables of built-in type, this form of initialization
>   has one
>   **important property**: The compiler will not let us list initialize variables of built-in type if the initializer might lead to the loss
>   of information:

```
longdouble ld = 3.1415926536;
int a{ld}, b = {ld}; // error: narrowing conversion required
int c(ld), d = ld;  // ok: but value will be truncate
```

I compile the code using gcc4.8.1 , it only give a warning rather than an error.

```
g++  -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++0x  -o m main.cpp


main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:64:13: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘ld’ from ‘long double’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
     int a{ld}, b= {ld}; 
             ^
main.cpp:64:22: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘ld’ from ‘long double’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
     int a{ld}, b= {ld};
```

Is there any flags that will turn on the feature of the **important property** ?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but "C++0x" was the provisional nickname for the C++ standard that was finally ratified in 2011. Accordingly you can give your version of gcc the option `-std=c++11` to request conformance to the latest standard (and `-std=c++1y` to request conformance to the draft standard expected to be ratified in 2014).

Comment: got the same result using c++11,c++1y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search for "gcc diagnostic flag" turns up documentation resources.

Inside your program, you could do this:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#   pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wnarrowing"
#endif
```

There is a command-line option too: `-Werror=narrowing`, but since you want to alter the semantic meaning of the program itself according to GCC, putting it in the source code is probably more appropriate.

Note, when it makes a difference other than simple well-formedness, such as in overload selection, GCC does diagnose the condition correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The standard never calls for errors or for warnings: the standard only requires an implementation to issue a *diagnostic*. Whether such a diagnostic takes the form of a compiler error, or a warning, or something entirely different from them both, is outside the scope of the standard.

Comment: By the strictest definition, the compiler could just unconditionally say "`oops`" and call that a catch-all diagnostic message, which also happens to be issued in case of success. People do have practical requirements as well. The usual expectation is that if the compiler is not "accepting" the program per §1.4/2, it won't write an executable file, which is probably what irks @camino.