# why is braced initialization not giving error when an int is initialized to floating point value?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, c++14, list-initialization

I am studying C++ from C++ Primer by Josée Lajoie and Stanley B. Lippman. I read that when variables are initialized using curly braces and if the initialization results in loss of data then an error occurs.

```
double a=5.545;
int b{a};
std::cout<<b;
```

But when I run the above code I am not getting any error and getting the output as 5.

PS: I am using CLion IDE and MingW C++ compiler.

Comment: Turn on warnings.

Comment: Didn't you get a warning?

Comment: I got a warning. But am I not supposed to get a error?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17560389/560648 https://stackoverflow.com/q/12873919/560648

Answer (score 1):

The book is wrong. Construction of an `int` from a `double` is perfectly normal and commonplace, and it *will* lose data (all the fractional parts!). This is not in any way an error.

Your compiler may *warn* you about the loss of data if it can be sure that there will be some. That's it being kind. But the general principle is that, by writing this code, you literally said "I want to lose the fractional parts please".

If you turn on "warnings as errors", then any such warning gets converted into an error and halts the build. But that's not related to the conversion itself.

Comment: The book is definitely correct. [List initialization doesn't allow such narrowing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Narrowing_conversions).

Comment: List-initialization does not apply here, because int is a fundamental type and does not have a [constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113365/do-built-in-types-have-default-constructors).

Comment: @FlorianM. Please read the link above, the first clause of prohibition is "conversion from a floating-point type to an integer type". This is [how clang correctly rejects OP's code](https://godbolt.org/g/NJXR92) without any special warning level.

Comment: @liliscent: Hmm seems you're right - however, the end result is still compliant. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12874041/560648

Comment: @liliscent I have read the link carefully before I posted my answer. And I think that list-initialization is not used here, because that would require a constructor (IMHO). But there is another point, which I overlooked: Otherwise (if T is not a class type), if the braced-init-list has only one element and either T isn't a reference type or is a reference type that is compatible with the type of the element, T is direct-initialized (in direct-list-initialization) or copy-initialized (in copy-list-initialization), except that narrowing conversions are not allowed. 
--> So I agree with you

Comment: It's not a good answer if it declares code that is not valid C++ to not contain errors "in any way". You are right that a compiler is not required to emit an error, and in such a way to can even say that "int my main to me;" is not in any way an error, because your compiler may just emit a warning about it (and then does whatever). But this isn't useful at all.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: We've already established that

Comment: So while you are right about the compiler and the distinction between error messages and diagnostics, you are wrong about your initial statement "The book is wrong". It is actually right: An error occurs in compilers in which the diagnostic message is given as an error message for that invalid C++ snippet.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Yes, I agree - again, we have already discussed all of this.

Comment: Have you ever tried deleting an accepted answer?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm with you on this. I know this feeling. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340966/what-should-i-do-when-my-accepted-answer-turns-out-to-be-inappropriate

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I remember that one :)